# Sounds or meta-strips from VSE through a speaker object?

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor, audio

I am playing sounds when various falling objects hit other objects, like the ground. I have them playing sounds that I've assembled to match timing in the VSE.

Is there a way to play these sequences as a single sound using a speaker object without having to render each object's sounds into a new file first?

My goal is to attach the speaker object to the falling object so that my camera's will render out 3D audio based on the positioning as they fly through the scene.

I was thinking of having a meta-strip and pointing the speaker object to use the meta-strip...but that doesn't look possible. It would just make it so EASY!

Maybe I'm missing the obvious here.

Comment: Yes, it would make it easy. But actually you find the _Pipeline_ settings (to use _Compositing_ and/or _Sequencer_) in the **_Post Processing_** options of the _Output Properties_. Whatever you have in your scene, when you want to render an image or animation, first the render layers will be rendered and afterwards will be calculated whatever you have set up in the _Compositor_ or the _Sequencer_. So in the moment of rendering any strips are not available in the scene.